# Is there a quick way to remove/undo a merged pull request in the upstream branch from my fork?

Tags: git, github

I want to remove [this pull request](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/81138) from my fork of the Godot engine because it breaks my imported models. Is there any way to do that without me modifying 59 changed files manually?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simply create a revert commit using `git revert <hash-of-the-commit-you-want-to-revert>`.

Reference - https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert